# Load HTML into Div on background thread?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multithreading

I'm loading an external HTML file into a DIV using the following method:

```
    var docName = name + ".html";
    $("#displayPanel").load(docName);
```

then I call getScript on the javascript file controlling that HTML file, like so:

```
    docName = name + ".js";
    $.getScript(docName, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {

        if (textStatus==="success") {
            lightItUp(); //load method
        }
    });
```

It loads correctly.

The issue is that with large HTML/JS files the DOM is frozen and user interaction is disabled until the load has completed. Is it possible to put the div loading on a 'background thread' and receive a completion notification?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers). You could get the Web Worker to parse the HTML, then inject the HTML into the parent web page in batches using messages

Comment: I believe jQuery.getScript() is asynchronous and loads the script in "background thread".

Comment: Are you setting global ajax to sync or what? `$.getScript()` shouldn't freeze UI, looks like issue comes from `lightItUp()` instead or more obviously you are misinterpreting behaviour you see. BTW, you don't need to check for `textStatus`, you are already setting code inside success callback. EDIT: i'm not sure about what you expect regarding `textStatus` check

Comment: Thank you for your help --> the lightItUp() method is the bottleneck. I'll hide / fade the UI to make it appear to load quicker, even if other elements on the screen are not responsive (e.g. hover changes on buttons). 

In iOS development it's possible to put whole methods on "background threads" and forget about them until they complete (sending a notification) was curious if this was possible with web languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly.

If you want to make it as if the div is loading on a background thread and receive a notif upon completion, you can have the div `display:none` at first and make it `display:block` in the callback.

```
$( "#aDivInDisplayPanel" ).load( docName, function() {
  //load completed.
  $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using HTML5 Web Workers?

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

> When executing scripts in an HTML page, the page becomes unresponsive
>   until the script is finished.
>
> A web worker is a JavaScript that runs in the background,
>   independently of other scripts, without affecting the performance of
>   the page. You can continue to do whatever you want: clicking,
>   selecting things, etc., while the web worker runs in the background.

Comment: FYI, linking to W3Schools is generally frowned upon for a few reasons: http://www.w3fools.com/ - You should link to a more reputable source such as MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: I take your point onboard. How about HTML5 Rocks: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Comment: That's also a very good resource, although being a blog information can get outdated quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you make AJAX synchronous somehow, the code above can't block the UI unless the browser needs a long time to process the HTML (IE 6.6 could take 1-2 minutes to parse HTML loaded this way) or you have something in `lightItUp()` that takes a long time.

The next step is to fire up your browser's performance tool and check where the time goes. The code that you posted above looks correct and should not cause what you describe.